# Finding the image of a line under a complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm finding that the image of a line is harder to inspect (visualising is fine, just finding the equation just by inspecting the visualisation is harder) under some complex-valued function.

Given that $y=2x+5$, find the image of the line under $w(z) = (1+i)z - 2$.
First, I let $z = x+iy = x + i(2x+5)$ and $w:= u+iv$.
Then solving for $u,v$ I get $v=-16-3u$.
However, the solutions say: $v = 14-3u$.
Did I approach the question incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

$v=14-3u$ is instead wrong.

Check for a single point belonging to the line $y=2x+5$ and see where it is mapped. For instance, for $x=0$, $y=5$, then $w(5i)=-7+5i$, that does not belong to the line $v=14-3u$, because when $u=-7$, then $v\ne 5$